# Meaning of 'on a reader'

Tags: meaning

What does **reader** mean here? I simply can't find a proper meaning for this anywhere in dictionaries.

> There was something about Jerry's face that worried me. As if I had seen him before, but not very lately, or in a newspaper photo.
>   ...
>   "I've seen him somewhere. Maybe on a reader."

<sub>From Raymond Chandler's "[The man who liked dogs](http://www.ae-lib.org.ua/texts-c/chandler__the_man_who_liked_dogs__en.htm)" (1936)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [wanted poster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanted_poster):

> *U.S. colloq.* A police circular identifying a wanted person; a ‘wanted’ poster.
>   <sub>www.oed.com</sub>

According to the [Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=KT-cAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA243), it was used between 1922 and 1955 (which explains why it's not in most dictionaries).